# Python psycopg2 postgres select columns including field names

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Hi I'd like to get a table from a database, but include the field names so I can use them from column headings in e.g. Pandas where I don't necessarily know all the field names in advance

so if my database looks like

`table test1`

```
 a | b | c 
---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 3
 1 | 2 | 3
 1 | 2 | 3
 1 | 2 | 3
 1 | 2 | 3
```

How can I do a

```
import psycopg2 as pq
cn = pq.connect('dbname=mydb user=me')
cr = cn.cursor()
cr.execute('SELECT * FROM test1;')
tmp = cr.fetchall()
tmp
```

such that tmp shows

```
[('a','b','c'),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

Thanks

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Nice. I was going to suggest fetching from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but that's much more flexible as it isn't limited to just tables.

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not clear how to use that as an answer to my question. `cr.description(test1)` doesn't work. If you put it into an answer I'd be happy to mark it up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The column names are available as `cr.description[0][0]`, `cr.description[1][0]`, etc.  If you want it in exactly the format you show, you need to do some work to extract it and stick it in front of the result set.

Answer (score 17):

If what you want is a dataframe with the data from the db table as its values and the dataframe column names being the field names you read in from the db, then this should do what you want:

```
import psycopg2 as pq
cn = pq.connect('dbname=mydb user=me')
cr = cn.cursor()
cr.execute('SELECT * FROM test1;')
tmp = cr.fetchall()

# Extract the column names
col_names = []
for elt in cr.description:
    col_names.append(elt[0])

# Create the dataframe, passing in the list of col_names extracted from the description
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=col_names)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also map over it which looks a bit nicer:

```
cursor.execute(open("blah.sql", "r").read())
data = cursor.fetchall()
cols = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cursor.description))
df = DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use two loop cases, to not use pandas:

```
temp = []
for x in result:
    temp2 = {}
    c = 0
    for col in cursor.description:
        temp2.update({str(col[0]): x[c]})
        c = c+1
    temp.append(temp2)
print(temp)
```

This will prints any like this:

```
[{'column1':'foo1','column2':'foo1'},{'column1':'foo2','column2':'foo2'},...]
```

I hope this help you! Cheers

Comment: I think this is the best answer - simple and actually works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import psycopg2 as pq
cn = pq.connect('dbname=mydb user=me')
cr = cn.cursor()
cr.execute('SELECT * FROM test1;')
tmp = cr.fetchall() #Hi, these are your codes that build a connection to a psql server

cols = []
for col in tmp.description:
    cols.append(col[0]) #Collect all column names into an empty list, cols    
tmp.insert(0, tuple(cols)) #insert elements by list.insert(index, new_item) method
```

The output is

```
[('a','b','c'),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Crossposting this from my answer to a nearly identical question.

You shouldn't have to assign column names in a separate statement nor do any looping.

```
import psycopg2, pandas

con=psycopg2.connect(
    dbname=DBNAME, 
    host=HOST, 
    port=PORT, 
    user=USER, 
    password=PASSWORD
)

sql = """
select * from x
"""

d = pandas.read_sql_query(sql,con)

con.close()

print(type(d))

print(pandas.DataFrame.head(d))
```